# ngrx removing item from list when using dispatch

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have angular 8 application. And i am using ngrx for state management.

But the problem is , that if I try to remove item, it wiil redirect to other tab. and not removing item.

So I have this:

reducer:

```
const intialState: Tutorial = {
  name: 'initial State',
  url: 'http://google.com'
};

export function tutorialReducer(state: Tutorial[] = [intialState], action: TutorialActions.Actions) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TutorialActions.ADD_TUTORIAL:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case TutorialActions.DELETE_TUTORIAL:
      state.splice(action.payload, 1);
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions:

```
export class AddTutorial implements Action {
  readonly type = ADD_TUTORIAL;

  constructor(public payload: Tutorial) {}
}

export class RemoveTutorial implements Action {
  readonly type = DELETE_TUTORIAL;

  constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type Actions = AddTutorial | RemoveTutorial;
```

and remove template:

```
<div class="right" *ngIf="tutorials$">
  <h3>Tutorials</h3>

  <ul>
    <li (click)="delTutorial(i)" *ngFor="let tutorial of tutorials$ | async; let i = index">
      <a [href]="tutorial.url" target="_blank">{{ tutorial.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and ts code:

```
export class ReadComponent implements OnInit {

  tutorials$: Observable<Tutorial[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
  this.tutorials$ = this.store.select('tutorial');
  }

 delTutorial(index){
    this.store.dispatch(new TutorialActions.RemoveTutorial(index));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and app.module.ts:

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({tutorial: tutorialReducer}),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

But so it doesnt remove item, but acturally opens a new tab.

ANd then I get this error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '5' of object '[object Array]'
    at Array.splice (<anonymous>)
    at tutorialReducer (tutorial.reducers.ts:16)
    at combination (store.js:303)
    at store.js:1213
    at store.js:38
```

So what I have to change? So that you can remove a item from the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is immutable. So, you cannot change the state in the reducer.
You have to return a new modified value without changing the current state.

```
case TutorialActions.DELETE_TUTORIAL:
  let newState = [...state]; 
  newState.splice(action.payload, 1);
  return newState;
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend following things:

- you should avoid mutating the state directly.
- Create a copy of your state then perform the operation
- One more thing to remember is that splice takes the first argument as the index of the element which you want to remove.
- Find the indexOf the payload or item from the array
- Then use this index to splice the array element.
- Eg:

> ```
> var array = [...state]; // make a separate copy of the array or state
>   var index = array.indexOf(your_payload_toberemoved)
>   if (index !== -1) {
>     array.splice(index, 1);
>    return array
>   }
> ```

I hope you find these points helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Very nice. I just give one solution a mark. But I up voted you

Comment: I appreciate your consideration @savantTheCoder